# Transforming EntityType dropdown form field into autocomplete (symfony 3)

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, symfony-3.4

I am working with symfony 3.4. I would need to change EntityType form field which is currently a dropdown-list into autocomplete.
I have just started my adventure with Symfony. Could someone help me in this matter?